# Prove $\forall x \in \mathbb{R}$: $[\sinh(x)+\cosh(x)]^n = \cosh(nx)+\sinh(nx)$ ; $ n\in \mathbb{Q}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, hyperbolic-functions

How to prove?

Prove $\forall x \in \mathbb{R}$: $[\sinh(x)+\cosh(x)]^n = \cosh(nx)+\sinh(nx)$ ; $ n\in \mathbb{Q}$

Comment: Is it important that $n\in \mathbb{Q}$ ?

Comment: Yes, it important?

Comment: It holds for real numbers. but is it hold for $n\in\mathbb{C}$ ?

Answer (score 7):

Solution: note that
$$
\sinh(x) + \cosh(x) = \frac {\mathrm e^x - \mathrm e^{-x}} 2 + \frac {\mathrm e^x + \mathrm e^{-x}} 2 = e^x,
$$
and rest is obvious.